# How to create an Entity with multiple tables? (Doctrine2)

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, orm, doctrine

There is a legacy project, which I would like to refactor. I would like to handle all database related stuff with `Doctrine`.

Unfortunately the user data is in two tables. There is a `x_users` and a `x_userdata` table. Both have a `user_id` field, but store different type of information. I would like to use all the columns from both tables in my `User` entity. How is it possible?

I was searching for a solution, but I haven't found any answer yet.

---

One solution would be to create a `User` and a `UserData` entity, and have a `one to one` relationship. But maybe there is a better solution

Comment: The D2 ORM is strictly one entity per table.  I suppose you could try creating a sql view and map that.  Otherwise, if you really want this sort of flexibility then drop the ORM and just use the DBAL connection object and do your own mapping.  Not that hard and lets you avoid the ORM limitations.